# Custom Post Type archive (archive-{post-type}.php) is not working

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

Many answers on this particular question, even on this site, but none of them fit me. Yes, I did all the things I know, and I got from previous answers, but my custom post type archive is not working:

```
<?php
function project_register_cpt_books() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Books', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No Book found', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No Book found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Book:', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'description'           => __( 'To get books information', 'textdomain' ),
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'books' ),
        'capability_type'       => 'post'
    );
    register_post_type( 'books', $args );

    /**
     * To Activate Custom Post Type Single page.
     * @author  Bainternet
     * @link http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-post-type-getting-404-on-permalinks
     * -----------
     */
    $set = get_option('post_type_rules_flased_books');
    if ($set !== true){
        flush_rewrite_rules(false);
        update_option('post_type_rules_flased_books',true);
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'project_register_cpt_books' );
```

Activation/Deactivation of theme, flashing permalink, checking both Default and PostName permalink, changing slug, changing/commenting out `rewrite` parameter... all failed. There's no way my `archive-books.php` is working. It's falling back to `archive.php` by all the means.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem, because I's causing the issue by myself unknowingly. I'm posting the answer for you to debug if something like this can cause the issue:

I's using the following code to include all the CPT entries to the default loop. And that's causing the issue. It's directing the posttype archive to default `post` archive (`archive.php`).

```
<?php
/**
 * Adding the Book entries to the loop.
 * @param object $query WordPress' default query object.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function project_add_book_entries_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'books') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'project_add_book_entries_to_query' );
```